# Istio Envoyproxy downstream_local_disconnect

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, istio-gateway

I am using Istio 1.15.x. I've enabled access logging.
At the Istio-Ingresstatway, I see this in response:

```
ResponseCode="0"    ResponseCodeDetails="downstream_local_disconnect"
```

The documentation mentions

> "The client connection was locally closed for the provided reason."

It's not clear where the provided reason is specified. There are no error logs from the ingress gateway pod as well.

Why did this get disconnected and how can i debug this further?